# Laravel uploading file is failing on production server

Tags: php, laravel, permissions

So I have a livewire component which uploads a file to the server and then lists the files added to the project. All is working fine on my dev environment when I use php artisan serve but now I have this moving into production it is not working. I have also setup a local apache conf file and accessing the site this way I also get a fail when uploading to storage.

Is this something I have missed in my .env file or such? My dev .env has the following partial content

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=production
APP_KEY=base64:etcetcetcnotrealvalueetcetcetc
APP_DEBUG=false
#APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000
APP_URL=https://laravel.testing.com:443
```

The rest of my site works as I expect just the uploads isn't. I can confirm that the uploads folder does exist but the subdirectory does not (I expect laravel to make the folder if it is not there right?). Either way I have also just added the subdirectory and it still doesn't upload so a bit lost really. error is not saying much "The uploads failed to upload."

Does anyone have a link to a tutorial/checklist on how to correctly configure a Laravel app to use storage with apache virtual hosts. After looking more I notice also that the profile image upload is also failing (and this also works on my dev site when using php artisan serve but not with the url listed above.

Just to note that the staging/production site is on a Digital Ocean VPN so I do have full access.

thanks

Comment: maybe some folder permission issue ?

Comment: Did you check the PHP Error log?

Comment: I have public/storage folder belonging to www-data:www-data and using 775 as of my last amends. I've also tried with $USER:www-data and 777 and also 755 none of them work unfortunately. Error log doesn't have any entries from since I started testing this feature

Comment: Check the laravel error log storage/logs

Comment: last entry in log in storage logs was when running composer earlier today. Oddly however i have a laravel.log (which has this error) but also one dated today (laravel-2022-06-06.log) which has a more recent error but this is again not related (It's an N+1 issue I'm aware of). My third log file (which is from apache and in a folder outside the app) has no entry since last week (these seem to be failed attempts to access the app like invalid URI path (/cgi-bin/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/.%2e/bin/sh) ) but nothing today!

Comment: Not sure is important but.... Did you run artisan command "storage:link?

Comment: Hi @nikistag, yes I even deleted and rebuilt it to rule it out.